# Spring LDAP throwing a NPE

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-ldap

I am using the following code to authenticate using spring LDAP.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String username = "kgam";
    String password = "password";

    LdapContextSource ctxSrc = new LdapContextSource();
    ctxSrc.setUrl(URL);
    ctxSrc.setBase(BASE);
    ctxSrc.setUserDn(USERDN);
    ctxSrc.setPassword(PASSWORD);
    LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(ctxSrc);
    AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
    ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);
    filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectClass", "person")).and(new EqualsFilter("sAMAccountName", username));
    System.out.println(ldapTemplate.authenticate(BASE, filter.toString(), password));
}
```

It throws a NPE with the following stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadOnlyContext(AbstractContextSource.java:138)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:286)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:236)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:623)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:534)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:461)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:482)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:502)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.authenticate(LdapTemplate.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.authenticate(LdapTemplate.java:1398)
    at com.capitalone.dashboard.service.AuthenticationServiceImpl.main(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:123)
```

Any ideas as to where I am wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configure Spring LDAP completely without help from Spring, like in your example, you need to call `afterPropertiesSet` on the `ContextSource` when you finished configuring it.